Prompt runs multiple times and I'd it like to run just once per click
I'm building a boxing or countdown timer. I have it working and updating the div content but when I add a prompt it gets called forever. I can see it update the div but it never lets the rest of my code run. Any tips to forge ahead will be much appreciated.
function timerStart() {
 let timerString = prompt("Enter Num");
 /*let timerString = document.getElementById("div0").textContent;*/
 let [minutes, seconds] = timerString.split(":").map(Number);

 if (seconds > 0) {
   seconds--;
   console.log(seconds);
 } else if (minutes > 0) {
   minutes--;
   seconds = 59;
   console.log(minutes);
 } else {
   clearInterval(intervalTime);
   return;
 }
 let newTimerString = `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${seconds
   .toString()
   .padStart(2, "0")}`;
 document.getElementById("div0").textContent = newTimerString;
}

function startTimer() {
 intervalTime = setInterval(timerStart, 1000);
}

document.getElementById("butt").addEventListener("click", startTimer);`

I've tried putting the prompt outside of the function but that obviously didn't work. I treid to return at the end of the prompt but stops the function.

Make another function that will first prompt then call the interval. In order to pass the value of time from one function to another, I am using global variables.


var minutes, seconds

function timerStart() {

  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds--;
    console.log(seconds);
  } else if (minutes > 0) {
    minutes--;
    seconds = 59;
    console.log(minutes);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalTime);
    return;
  }
  let newTimerString = `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${seconds
   .toString()
   .padStart(2, "0")}`;
  document.getElementById("div0").textContent = newTimerString;
}

function startTimer() {
  intervalTime = setInterval(timerStart, 1000);
}

function promptThenStartTimer() {
  let timerString = prompt("Enter Num");
  [minutes, seconds] = timerString.split(":").map(Number);
  startTimer()
}


document.getElementById("butt").addEventListener("click", promptThenStartTimer);
<button id="butt">click</button>
<div id="div0"></div>




Thank you, it worked! I appreciate your help!
